# Prisma return unanswered questions

Tags: typescript, next.js, prisma

Question and Answer tables are related and I want to return unanswered questions. I tried `where` and `having` but it just doesn't seem to work. I get

> 'where' does not exist in type 'QuestionInclude'.ts(2322)

```
const questions = await db.question.findMany({
  orderBy: {
    createdAt: "desc",
  },

  include: {
    topic: true,
    votes: true,
    author: true,

    _count: {
      select: {
        answers: true,
      },
    },
  },
 where: {
    _count: {
      answers: {
        equals: 0,
      },
    },
  },
  take: INFINITE_SCROLL_PAGINATION_RESULTS, 
});
```

Comment: @mkrieger1 Sorry, I just included where. It seems I am unable to get some hint from the documentation–